# UI takes from 20 up to 25% of my screen vertical space

Tags: chrome, user-interface

I use `google-chrome-stable` (Version 69.0.3497.100, installed from the official Google repository) on my Debian Sid laptop.

Its user interface (UI) sits at the top of the window and, as far as I can remember, it took for itself a good amount of space forever  but following a recent update, the UI itself takes about 20% of the vertical space of my screen.

That's all when Chrome is full screen, but adding the window decoration raise the percentage to about 25%.  This happens because the new UI design adds LARGE amounts of vertical space between everything!

I have to say that I have in sight ① the tabs bar ② the address bar and ③ the bookmars bar and I could remove e.g. the bookmarks, but...

What can I do to reduce the vertical space used by the new Chrome UI?